# cant reach variabel in ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, get

I'm trying to reach a variable from another php file and set this in a chart. Sadly the chart is showing nothing (since the start value of `MachineActivityS = 0`). When I REMOVE `var MachineActivityS = 0;` it says: `MachineActivityS isn't defined`. If I set everything of the chart in the AJAX code it won't display the chart.

Below you can find the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var MachineActivityS = 0;
$.ajax
({

url: 'MachineActivityS.php',
type: 'get',
success: function(response)
    {
        MachineActivityS = response;
    },
});

var hours =  parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
var amountOfProducts = Math.floor(((hours * 60) + minutes) * 1.8);

var barChartData = 
{
    labels : ["Activity in minutes","Number of products"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [minutes + (hours * 60), amountOfProducts]
        }

    ]

}

window.onload = function()
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : false,
        animation: false        
    });
}   
</script>
```

How can I reach the value in that file and set it in my chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a new `MachineActivityS` in your callback. So change

```
success: function(response) {
  var MachineActivityS = response;
}
```

to this:

```
success: function(response) {
  MachineActivityS = response;
}
```

Also, since your AJAX call runs asynchronously, you'll want to move everything that uses `MachineActivityS` into that callback as well.

```
success: function(MachineActivityS) {
  var hours =  parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
  var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
  var amountOfProducts = Math.floor(((hours * 60) + minutes) * 1.8);
  ...
}
```

**Edit**: To ensure that your chart draws after the page has loaded and your AJAX call returns, move your `$.ajax` call into your `window.onload` event handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function(MachineActivityS) {
      var hours =  parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
      var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
      var amountOfProducts = Math.floor(((hours * 60) + minutes) * 1.8);

      var barChartData = ...;

      var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : false,
        animation: false        
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thats what I said, I cant move everything in it, since it won't display the char then. Even when I only place a part without the barChartData it can't reach minutes and hours...

Comment: That's because you're drawing the code on page load. That probably happens before your AJAX call returns. Move the AJAX call inside of your page load handler.

Comment: Well can u give an example, I dont know what you exactly mean

Comment: Still same problem: Uncaught ReferenceError: MachineActivityS is not defined. Even when I set the definition outside the function. He won't take the data out of the other page.

Comment: @Bart Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) because that should not be possible.

Comment: How can I add  reference files to it..? for instance the MachineActivityMin.php and Chart.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73257/discussion-between-mike-c-and-bart).